# File handling in getline function

Tags: c++, getline, file-handling

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
 A          4     6
 B          5     7
 c          4     8
```

I want to store it in three different arrays:

```
char pro[];     // contains values A B C
int arrival[];  // contains values of 4 5 5
int Burst[];    // contains values of 6 7 8
```

I don't know how to do that. Any help (tutorials, pseudo code etc.) is appreciated.

Comment: If the number of lines is known and is some constant then indeed you can use arrays. Otherwise you should use some standard containers as for example std::vector.

Comment: pseudo code : 1. get data from file 2. store it in array. Haha jk , you need to open that file using file io . then read from that file (you can use file>>ch,file>>int1,file>>int2 repeatedly in a loop too and store these variable into array/vector.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my proposal. Hope that helps.

Basically what it does, it creates three containers (see std::vector from STL). They can have infinite size (you don't have to declare it afront). The create three auxilliary variables which you then use to read from stream.

The condition in while loop checks if data is still in the file stream.
I did not use .eof() method because it always reads the last line in a file twice.

```html
using namespaces std;

int main() {

vector<char> pro;
vector<int> arrival;
vector<int> Burst;

/* your code here */

char temp;
int number1, number2;


ifstream file;
file.open("text.txt");

if( !(file.is_open()))
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

while (file >> temp >> number1 >> number2)
{
  pro.push_back(temp);
  arrival.push_back(number1);
  Burst.push_back(number2);
}

file.close();

}
```